# How can I prove that a set is a basis for a rack?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a set X we will call $((X, F(X)), *, *^{-1}) =: R$ a free rack (F(X) being a set of all words on X), if the following holds:

1. $(a, u) * (b, v) = (a, u v^{-1} bv)$
2. $(a, u) *^{-1} (b, v) = (a, u v^{-1} b^{-1} v)$

Now I need to find a criteria that a subset S of (X, F(X)) is basis for a free subrack, i.e. that there are no relations among its elements. For example, is it sufficient for the set S to have a basis of free group for its second coordinates? I also tried the Shrier method, but it didn’t work. All ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some details, e.g. what is a 'rack'? And where is this question coming from?

Comment: Well, as for groups, racks (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) can be represented as a free rack modulo some relations. Wherefore I am looking for some other analogies to the group theory